# preventing default event on axios error in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to prevent opening of link in react if axios.post gets error.
I used `event.preventDefault` but it isnt stopping the link from opening on button click.
Here is the code

```
<Link
to={{
  pathname: '/',
  data: "success",
}}
>
<div>
  <Button
    onClick={this.onSubmit}
    variant="contained"
    color="secondary"
  >
    Post
  </Button>
</div>
</Link>
onSubmit=(ev)=>{
   let data = {
          title: this.state.title,
          content: this.state.content,
          username: this.state.data.xusername,
          date: new Date().toUTCString(),
        };
        Axios.post("http://localhost:9000/posts", data)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            console.log(error);
          });
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do here but by the time your calling preventDefault it's already opened the link..

Comment: Yeah... This simply makes no sense. Why have the button within the link? If you want to redirect to another page upon axios promise resolving, and to stay if there's an error, this is not the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a button nested within a link is your problem. This means that when you click the button, it's the **button event** your preventing default on.

If you want to redirect to another page upon axios call completion, you could do so with something like this:

```
<Button
  onClick={this.onSubmit}
  variant="contained"
   color="secondary"
>
  Post
</Button>

onSubmit=(ev)=>{
let data = {
      title: this.state.title,
      content: this.state.content,
      username: this.state.data.xusername,
      date: new Date().toUTCString(),
    };
    Axios.post("http://localhost:9000/posts", data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        window.location.replace("/yourpage?var1=value"); // Redirect with vanilla js.
        this.props.history.push('/yourpage?var1=value&var2=value'); // Redirect with reactjs.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error); // On error, user will experience no change.
      });
```

Comment: thanks for pointing the problem but how can i send data to "/yourpage" then

Comment: I edited the answer. I added the proper way to redirect with react, as opposed to vanilla js. I also added the syntax for passing query strings, which is how you would send data. I see your a new user. Welcome! Please mark this as the correct answer if my answer helped you.